# Drawing angle between 2 rays

Tags: unity, debugging, viewport

Currently, we can draw rays in real time, like this:

```
Debug.DrawRay(transform.localPosition, _navAgent.desiredVelocity*3, Color.yellow);
Debug.DrawRay(transform.localPosition, transform.forward*2, Color.magenta);
```

Is there some way we can draw the angle between these two rays for real time visualization? I'd like to draw them in the viewport at the intersection of the two rays, instead of having to log it in the editor and trying to guess which angle was for which frame. For example, below we can see the viewport showing the above two rays, one is the navAgent's `desiredVelocityVector`(yellow) and the other the character's `forward vector`(magenta), I've drawn the angle construction I imagine I'd like to be able to view (in green): [image]

Comment: Sure, we can make our own convenience function that combines Debug.DrawLine calls to make any shape we want. What would you like the drawn angle to look like?

Comment: Like the usual angle symbol we see in mathematics, it would be visually appealing if it drew as an arc between the two rays

Comment: So you want just a semi-circular arc between two rays, no numeric display?

Comment: no, a numeric display that goes with the arc would be best I think

Comment: Then you should **edit your question** to show us an example of what you want it to look like. Otherwise it's ambiguous what outcome you want.

Comment: @DMGregory , I've edited my question, thanks for the suggestion

Comment: I assume using a world-space canvas would be overkill?

Comment: I don't know, I did use a canvas to render on screen, but not like I show above. And, I also didn't know how to make the canvas always parallel to the camera